# "start" action on right-click

Tags: windows-vista, virus, malware

I was hit with a virus the other day.  It was one of the viruses that pretend to be anti-virus software and keep hitting you with fake warning messages.

I ran spybot and malware bytes, and the virus, i think was removed.

I have noticed that when I right-click on an executable, I get an option called "start".

[image]

This looks fishy to me because it isnt even capitalized, and it is very vague.

I have updated spybot and malware bytes, and ran them again, but both programs found nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You hit two of the three legs in the stool.  Try running **[SUPERAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/)**.  The name and the site are cheesy, but I've had good results with it catching things the other two have missed.

Comment: I've never heard of this tool before today, which sets my skeptic bells ringing.  Anybody else ever used this?

Comment: Skeptics welcome: http://lifehacker.com/5628396/the-basic-guide-to-troubleshooting-common-windows-pc-problems

http://www.pcworld.com/article/227855/what_do_you_do_with_an_infected_cd_dvd_or_flash_drive.html

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/how-to-use-superantispyware-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for links to reputable sources, @Ray.  I'll have to look into this app.  (And now let's see how long it takes for somebody to call one of those 'not reputable'...)

Comment: I've used it. It caught things other programs missed.

Comment: good info but not the actual answer to question...

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/mse.aspx). Its free. Its fast. Its not annoying.

Comment: +1 - To continue mixing metaphors, the other shoe that needs to drop is keeping AV software up to date.  This is the one I use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Autoruns to find the context menu handler setting that "Start" function, but I'd save that for after I'd run a few more full scans while in safe mode or with the hard drive slaved into another box for the scan.

Answer (score 0):

It is common for malware to do this so exe will not launch and instead popup a message saying the file is infected, to fix this you will need to modify the registry:

Save the code below as a .reg and execute it, it should correct the issue:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command]
    @="\"%1\" %*"
    "IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try right click enhancer's right click editor tool. this tool can easily remove this.

[Download Right Click Enhancer](http://rbsoft.org)

Answer (score 0):

Download **SheelExView**:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

Run it. Once the extensions are loaded, sort them by Type.
Check for entries with "Context Menu" type.
You should find the suspicious entry there.
Disable/Delete it.